# Large database - Best way to display data on device?

Tags: ios, database, xcode, json, core-data

I am currently creating an iOS app, which connects to a database and asynchronously downloads a JSON object of data to display in a table view.

As it currently stands, this is an ok way to do it. However, when the database starts getting much larger, this will cause a massive inconvenience. I'm reasonably proficient in Objective-C but not so much in the database side of things. What would be the best way to get this data from the server, and keep it in the app? At the moment, I have a custom class object storing the data for each of the 'objects' in the JSON object. There will however be many other aspects of the app that the database will handle, such as invites, logins and user details.

Would core data be the way to go? I.e duplicating the database (to a certain extent) and storing it locally, then accessing from there. As I said, i'm not really sure which route to take here, so any advice would be real appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core location is for handling location (satellite (and wifi) positionning).

I guess you mean Core Data. Core Data is a graph object model which allows you to manipulate data as objects. You don't dig directly into the database, you ask for objects instanciation through predicates (kind of where clause in SQL) and the manipulate the objects.

This stated, it all depends on what is a "big" database. If it's really big you could consider copying locally a part of it and ask for what's remaining from the server through your webservice.

Another question that you could ask yourself is the quantity of data that never change and if your website database and your app database needs to get synchronized (if your website database is always changing then it would be dumb to copy it in your app totally and always synced your app..).

Links :

[Introduction to Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/cdprogrammingguide.html)

[Difference between Core Data and a Database (Cocoa With Love)](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/02/differences-between-core-data-and.html)

---

edit :

A question you can ask yourself is where your data needs to be saved ?

if your app is just for printing 20 cells out of a total of 200 cells then i would go for a total download of your 200 cells. The load of the other cells will be with no delay after first download, especially appreciated if you're using table view cells with reusable cells

is a delay of some seconds acceptable between the 20 first cells and the 20 following ? I think there is no real "good" answer to your question, it depends on many factors (purpose of your app, acceptable time between loads, does the info needs to be modified and saved back to server or locally, what kind of customers, what your app will do with the cells, if you have a database locally will it be totally independant from "mother" database (if no, what kind of synchronization), etc.)

Trying to sum up things according to what I've understood of your needs, I would say that webservices is good if you just need to retrieve info and exploiting it after without saving it back (even if you can do it actually having services allowing you to do it), having a database locally is good if you need your app to be independant from your server in some ways.

Only you has the key to answer all this and take a decision according to your needs and your knowledge of your application and your customers.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did mean core data, I've changed that now. And for example, the Facebook app news feed. I obviously don't want to load all of the data from the server and populate ~100/200 cells. 10-20 would be ideal, then asking the user if they would like to load more when they reach the bottom. Is JSON still the way to go?

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it. For example, we may have an invites feature in which people can invite other friends, and said invites will be stored in a tab containing a table view. Would the best way be for these be downloaded when the app starts and then kept in an object class?

Comment: if you have a few invites named people you can even store them in an NSArray and write them into a file on disk (using the writeToFile: method) then retrieve it at launch (using initWithContentOfFile: method of NSArray). In that case setting up a database for 20 entries is overkill, store the data into a file.

Answer (score 0):

Something like JSON or SOAP is the way to go with getting structured data from a web service into objects in your iPhone app.

Storing relational data on the iPhone itself is easy with SQLite. [Here's a decent looking tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/902/sqlite-101-for-iphone-developers-creating-and-scripting).

Make things easy for yourself by writing a data layer, abstracting away calls to the database, to avoid dotting SQL queries all over your code in places it shouldn't be, like the UI.