# Which Type of database is best

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.2

In my app I use a static database to store all counties and census areas with the states and territories of the US.  This gets updated by the government every 10 years.  I use it to search within a county but there are multiple counties of the same name so a state or territory has to be picked first then they select the county within.  My question is that I currently have that data in an SQLite database, is that the most efficient or should I use core data?  Ther are 3600 lines with 4 items on each line. I just want it to be the most efficient way of storing and reading the data.  There will be no writing to it.  So which should I choose, I'm open to others than the two I mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for you case:

core data:

more flexible

- (+) it's a [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-Relational_Mapping) (a big plus! So you can add methods to your data models or store whole object-trees with one command)
- (+) better integrated into XCode
- (+) can easy handle migration of the data scheme
- (-) performance (in your case, 3600records only one table)

sqlite:

- (+)performance
- (-)only C bindings (or you need a
  framework)

and don't forget, CoreData is another layer on the top of sqlite. So,.. it's not so easy to compare those both things.

Comment: The con of only C bindings slipped my mind. Thank you for the pros and cons

Answer (score 0):

Core data is not a database, it's an object model graph, based upon a database which may (or not) be SQLite.

Using CoreData would need to rebuild all your queries in your app. You're using a rather small  and static database, which, I guess, is working fine. Why do you want to change ? Does your app experiencing some speed problems (in that case set up an index on your columns)? Whatever your choice may be, I bet you won't notice any improvement from a database to another with such a simple and small database.

You can look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9846152/large-database-best-way-to-display-data-on-device/9846325#9846325) about CoreData.

Comment: I'm not experiencing any problems but that doesn't mean my selection was correct or the most efficient. I just want it to be clean and thought I would get some opinions.  No problem in changing the coding, just want to be efficient when Apple reviews it.

Comment: Apple doesn't look at your source code, and they don't tend to look at the low-level details like whether you're using SQLite or Core Data. They won't give you extra credit for writing extra fast code. They care more about what end users see.